# Media Query Email

Tags: html, css, email, media-queries, responsive

I create responsive HTML emails with media queries, but in Gmail / Outlook / Inbox, max-width in the media query refers to the **browser viewport**, instead of the HTML email.

So, on localhost, my emails switch to mobile display under 700px, in Gmail / Outlook / Inbox, this comportement is broken.

Do you have a solution to make the **media query take as viewport the mail viewport instead of the browser viewport** ?

Answer (score 1):

No.

In theory, JavaScript could do this, but you can't write JavaScript to run in HTML formatted emails.

[Container queries](https://ishadeed.com/article/say-hello-to-css-container-queries/) could also do this, but they are so bleeding edge that, at the time of writing, only Chrome supports then and then only if the user explicitly enables the functionality in the settings.